# How to close the 3px gap in the bottom when hovering?

Tags: html, css

Ive struggling with a problem where my button don't stretch the full height of the parent div. When i hover the button its a ~3px gap from bottom of my button down to the parent divs bottom.

Ive broken down my whole code down to that little code down under here and the problem is still there. If i use `float: left;` on `#main_buttons`, `#header_big` and `.buttons` the problem is gone. But if i use float on `#main_buttons`, `#header_big` my whole site collapses, so that is not a fix without me having to recode the rest of the site as well. Is there any other solution? https://jsfiddle.net/ewktoqrL/

```
#header_big {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#main_buttons {
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.buttons {
  max-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.buttons:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
}


<div id="header_big">
  <div id="main_buttons">
    <div id="home" class="buttons">
      Home
    </div>
    <div id="cv" class="buttons">
      CV
    </div>
    <div id="nyheter" class="buttons">
      Nyheter
    </div>
    <div id="movie" class="buttons">
      Film
    </div>
    <div id="games" class="buttons">
      Spill
    </div>
    <div id="music" class="buttons">
      Musikk
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add `margin-bottom: -3px;` on your `.buttons`. I think that'll solve your problem. However, I'm not sure where the problems come from. I think it might comes from those padding in `.buttons`.